# Chef cron job not running

Tags: linux, cron, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a Chef cron job that will not run for the life of me, I think the cron job format is correct since I used `language-chef` in atom to create it and it matches examples on the docs. I have played around with the timing and nothing works. I have ran the command in the cron job by itself and it runs just fine so my command is correct.

**Cron job**

```
cron 'upl_base_backup.sh_cron' do
  minute '0'
  hour '1'
  weekday '6'
  command '/work-disk/postgresql-scripts/upl_base_backup.sh'
end
```

**Output of crontab -u root -l**

```
# Chef Name: upl_base_backup.sh_cron
0 1 * * 6 /work-disk/postgresql-scripts/upl_base_backup.sh
```

Any ideas on why it might not be running?

Answer (score 0):

First set the script to be executable.

`chmod +x /work-disk/postgresql-scripts/upl_base_backup.sh`

Second add the full path to the `sh` executable which should be `/bin/sh`. But you can find that yourself, using `whereis sh`.

The cron entry might look like this:

`0 1 * * 6 /bin/sh /work-disk/postgresql-scripts/upl_base_backup.sh`

Comment: The script can be run manually using the command given to chef.

As for the cron entry, I don't have control over how exactly it looks. I am using Chef with the `cron` resource.

Comment: I'm not a Chief expert, but try adding `sh -x` at the beginning of the command